# Are handle collisions possible in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I'm currently writing a library using OpenCL and wondered:

Is it possible for an OpenCL platform handle and an OpenCL device handle to have the same numeric value?

More generally: Are handle collisions between OpenCL objects of different types possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is up to the implementation. There is nothing in the spec saying these have to be unique across types, so they *could* be duplicated.